# Safari in-place video on iPad/iPod/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari

I am using JWPlayer for HTML5 video and curious about when iOS devices can or can't play in-place video on the device - or do they always display video full screen?

I have an iPod Touch with iOS 3.1.2 and when I load my page i get a video icon with a play button. It plays the H264 clip fullscreen just fine - but I was expecting it to play in place on the page.

What is preventing it playing in place? Is it the fact that it is a small screen, or an older iOS version.

Comment: I think only the iPad can play in place. The iPhone and iPod touch will display it fullscreen.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw. You should put that as an answer, that's exactly what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only the iPad can play in place. The iPhone and iPod touch will display it fullscreen.